# How to generate grid shapefile with grid squares that align with landmasses in R

Tags: r, vector-grid

I have a hard time trying to describe the shapefile exactly, but I am trying to generate a grid over the Gulf of St. Lawrence, such that only the gridsquares which lie over water are included. I would like this to extend to the narrow southern strait at (-60, 47)

I'm really new to GIS in R, and below is my attempt at brute forcing it by generating rows of gridsquares and specifying the bounding box for each line individually. I used st_make_grid from the sf library to make the 5 rows. 
Each gridsquare is 0.25x0.25 degrees.

[image]

I feel like there must be a more elegant solution to this... if anyone knows one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this isn't an elegant solution, but works:

```
library(sp)
library(maptools) # for example data
library(raster)

data(wrld_simpl)

r <- raster() # sample raster
res(r) <- c(5,5) # example resoution (I used a coarse one for speed up computation)

r[] <- 1:ncell(r) # this could be any value 

usa <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl$ISO3 == 'USA',] # example country

re <- raster::extract(r,usa, weights = T, normalizeWeights=F, cellnumber = T) # here you extract cell number intersected by usa, I put weights to filter

sup <- re[[1]][,'cell'][which(re[[1]][,'weight'] == 1)] # identify only cells with 100% land coverage, delteing [which(re[[1]][,'weight'] == 1)] you'll have sea-only pixels

r[sup] <- NA # remvoe values for this cells

poly <- as(r,'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame') # to grid

plot(usa);plot(poly,border='red',add=T) # plot
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to define clearly what inside and outside means, because you probably don't want lakes or rivers - but at any rate creating the polygons from a raster mask give some control.

Here I use `sf` version of Canada/USA states and produce all the polygons, then filter.

```
library(sf)
library(fasterize)
x <- rbind(rnaturalearth::ne_states( "United States of America", returnclass = "sf"), 
       rnaturalearth::ne_states( "Canada", returnclass = "sf"))
library(raster)
## grid template on a specific extent
r <- raster(extent(-75, -50, 42, 53), res = 0.25, crs = "+init=epsg:4326")


## fasterize
g <- fasterize(x, r)

## fast conversion pixel to polygons
p <- spex::polygonize(!is.na(g))
## layer is whether we were in or out of land
plot(subset(p, !layer)$geometry)
plot(x$geometry, add = TRUE)
```

[image]